# htaccess 301 Redirect urls with language variables to new static page

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to dynamically move around 500 urls that look like this:

```
/tag/NACHTISCH?lang=de

/tag/desertas?lang=lt
```

to a new url

I tried to do the following:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /tag/[a-zA-Z]\?lang\=[a-z]{2} /new-static-page-url
```

But that isn't working.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't you use `/tag/[a-zA-Z]*\?lang\=[a-z]{2}` ? (* after the first bracket)

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Anyone? I been on this for 10 hours.. grrr

Comment: `RedirectMatch 301 ^/tag/[a-zA-Z]*\?lang\=[a-z]{2}$ /new-static-page-url` ?